# Responsive image via media query CSS or inline backgroundImage in repeating template

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, handlebars.js

To show responsive image based on size when same HTML get repeated on HTML.

I am rendering below HTML which is working fine in (Chrome/Firefox/IE). I am rendering the div with css and changing a background-image using media query.
But a problem with this approach if the same template is used again on page with different images then on both place same css "market-promo-item__image" will get applying and display only one image.

However it's working fine in Chrome, Firefox on all dimensions.

```
<div class="market-product-item__image-wrapper">
  <div class="market-product-item__image"><!----></div>
  <style>
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
      .market-promo-item__image {
        background-image: url('//images.cloudfront.net/media/hero6-1_1920x520.jpg');
      }
    }
  </style>
  <div class="market-promo-item__image"><!----></div>
  <style>
    @media only screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
      .market-promo-item__image {
        background-image: url('//images.cloudfront.net/media/hero6-1_800x456.jpg');
      }
    }
  </style>
  <div class="market-promo-item__image"><!----></div>
  <style>
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .market-promo-item__image {
        background-image: url('//images.cloudfront.net/media/hero6-4_400x520.jpg');
      }
    }
  </style>
 </div>
```

I tried to use the "picture" element approach, but it's not working in IE11.
In IE 11 it's loading the image set in "src" attribute in `<img>` tag but when on changing (dimensions) size in IE11 it's not picking the correct image from srcset tags as per the screen size.

```
<picture>
  <source media="(max-width: 767px)" srcset="https://image.cloudfront.net/media/promo_big_550x470.jpg?h=j14yy1b">
  <source media="(max-width: 1023px)" srcset="https://image.cloudfront.net/media/promo_big1200x470.jpg?h=fgfqhin">
  <img class="market-promo-item__image lazy loaded" src="https://image.cloudfront.net/media/promo_big_1920x470.jpg?h=jcp5yqn " data-was-processed="true">      
</picture>
```

Comment: You should separate your styles into CSS files.

Comment: if I separated also problem will not resolve as same css  get apply if same template used again on page.

Comment: use css classes to isolate the responsive images ONLY on those elements present in that html page and isntead of having inline css rules which are both bad html coding and messes up structure with styling

Comment: agreed inline css is messes up the structure, will do that but apart from isolating the css name is there any other way to acheve objective ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to try to avoid inline CSS as much as possible. If I understood your question correctly, the reason why Images get overwritten when you use the same template multiple times on the same page, is caused by the way Browser parses document for HTML and CSS: style that is applied last, is the one which sticks(considering they all have the same specificity, which, judging by your code, they do).

To solve your problem, I would recommend to use 3 `img` tags — one `img` for one resolution. And add classes for 3 types of `img`, in order to show/hide them, based on resolution. Example:

```
<div class="market-product-item__image-wrapper">
  <div class="market-product-item__image">
    <img class="big-screen-img" href="//images.cloudfront.net/media/hero6-1_1920x520.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="medium-screen-img" href="//images.cloudfront.net/media/hero6-1_800x456.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="small-screen-img" href="//images.cloudfront.net/media/hero6-4_400x520.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Now you can add this CSS, in order to show/hide images for different screen resolutions:

```
.big-screen-img, .medium-screen-img, .small-screen-img {
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .big-screen-img {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
  .medium-screen-img {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .small-screen-img {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

This way, you can use the same structure through your whole page(repeating it wherever you need) And display only needed images based on resolution. If you will want to add another Image in other part of the Document, you only have to change `src` to new Images.

Hope that helps.

Comment: If you implement a `<div>` and set `background-image` and change the url at each break point, would you only need one element?

Comment: Yes, you would. I understood that question, as Image is meant to represent content — thus you have to use `img` tag(judging by the fact, that Author tried to implement this feature with `picture`). Using `div` with `background-image` would work just as you described, but it will require different classes to show different images, because of CSS parsing functionality, that I mentioned in my answer.